# Restore PostgreSQL database using only the tablespace files

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL on a Raspberry PI.  The database on the PI is set up to use a tablespace that is stored on a USB drive (so that I don't clog up the SD card).  My question is, would it be possible to recreate my database on another PC using just the tablespace files from the USB drive?  And if so how could I do this?  I want to know in case my other backups became corrupted and all I had left was the USB.

I've tried connecting the USB to my linux PC, copying the files to a new location, and changing the data_directory in the "/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf" file, but this led to a connection error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is absolutely impossible.

The data files for an object are meaningless without the object definition, which is stored in the catalog tables.

Moreover, table rows contain visibility information that relies on the transaction ID, which will be completely different on the target system.

There are various other data structures (multixacts, commit log) without which the information is unusable.

You need either a logical backup (`pg_dump`) or a physical backup (`pg_basebackup`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to do the backups.  Good to know the data couldn't be recreated just from the USB tablespace contents.